# sqlite insert or ignore always inserts on empty field

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am getting multiple inserts when a field is empty despite using `insert or ignore` with a primary key. I also tried adding a unique index, just to be sure. I only want new inserts when the primary key is not equal to any existing row.

According to [sqlite.org/nulls.html](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) `nulls are distinct in a UNIQUE column` these duplicate inserts should not happen.

I'm doing this insert:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO facts (
  created,
  inserted,
  author,
  kind,
  what,
  field,
  val
  ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS facts (
  created TEXT,
  inserted TEXT,
  author TEXT,
  kind TEXT,
  what TEXT,
  field TEXT,
  val TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(created, author, kind, what, field, val)
  )
```

and getting this result after doing the same inserts multiple times:

```
sqlite> select * from facts where what='vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn' order by inserted;
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643060|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|created|2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643152|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|alarm|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643315|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|deleted|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643380|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|description|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643445|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|location|KG45
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643641|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|summary|semtid
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:10.643780|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|when|TS('2014-03-14T07:00:00.000000', '2014-03-14T11:00:00.000000')
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:35.559110|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|alarm|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:23:35.559273|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|deleted|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:24:12.548969|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|alarm|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:24:12.549186|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|deleted|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:25:39.638743|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|alarm|
2014-01-29T09:30:44.000000|2015-07-23T13:25:39.638906|test_user_id|TaskFact|vot1dafjt95326qvs8kn|deleted|
```

The `deleted` and `alarm` rows are inserted multiple times, but the other rows are only inserted once.

I am doing the inserts from python3 using the `sqlite3` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting *"nulls are distinct in a UNIQUE column"*. It means that for the purposes of a `UNIQUE` constraint, `NULL == NULL` is false, so multiple `NULL`s can be inserted.

Note that technically, your columns are `PRIMARY KEY`, not `UNIQUE`. In SQL, primary keys are required to be `NOT NULL`; SQLite only supports `NULL` primary keys due to a bug-turned-feature.

Comment: so what can I do to not allow inserts of duplicate primary keys, as if `NULL == NULL` is true?

Comment: @FilipHaglund I don't think it's possible in SQLite. But your schema is a bit confusing; why do you want the value to be part of the key?

Comment: I want the history. When the value changes, I insert it again, with a newer timestamp. The entry with the latest timestamp is the correct one.

Comment: @FilipHaglund Make alarm/deleted a boolean then; store a 1 in their `val` column.

Comment: the best idea I have so far is to prepend a character to all strings, and remove it when fetching the data, since I have to be able to set a field to the value of an empty string

Comment: @FilipHaglund Empty strings and `NULL` are completely separate things. Empty strings are equal, can be concatenated, etc. `NULL` isn't equal to anything and most operations on them result in `NULL`. You can use empty strings in `val` and it will be unique. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/134872/102349

Comment: Turning all NULL values into empty strings fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!